# Algebraic construction of a state space system

Tags: numerical-methods, simulation

How could a state space system be automatically constructed based on the knowledge of underlying circuit?

E.g. -

[image]

$$ \dot{v_c}=\frac{-v_c}{CR}+\frac{V_{dc}}{CR} $$

That is, the representation is easy to figure out by hand.  But what would be the computer-based, algorithmic way?

Comment: You may want to start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_nodal_analysis).

Comment: Did you heard about the software Spice Simulator?

Comment: @Cesareo Of course I have - use it almost daily.  But I am looking to build a state-space, switched SPICE.